# vaadin form cannot hide null fields

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, field, vaadin

I have some vaadin forms which are reloaded after an event. The event causes some of the fields to become null. This means the form displays the label for the field and "null". I would like both the label and "null" value to disappear after the event is loaded. I would also like to do this without loading a different form to replace the form with the null values.

I have the following constructor for the form:

```
   public IInfoForm(Info info) {
    List<Object> orderedProperties =Arrays.asList(InfoContainer.DISPLAYED_FIELDS);
    setItemDataSource(new BeanItem(idInfo), orderedProperties);
```

The info container retrieves the data from a webservice and DISPLAYED_FIELDS lists the fields to display.
I have tried looking for properties to set on the form fields but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can set for any field a special value that stands for the null value. Example:

```
TextField textfield = new TextField();
textfield.setNullRepresentation("abc");
```

So instead of null "abc" is represented in the text field.

Create the fields by yourself and add them or add a FieldFactory to the form.

```
Form form = new Form();
form.setFormFieldFactory(new FormFieldFactory() {
    public Field createField(Item item, Object propertyId,
            Component uiContext) {
        Field field = DefaultFieldFactory.get().createField(item,
                propertyId, uiContext);
        if (field instanceof TextField) {
            ((TextField) field).setNullRepresentation("abc");
        }
        return field;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do so that I remove the fields with null value from the orderedProperties list and call

```
setItemDataSource(new BeanItem(idInfo), orderedProperties);
```

with that list.